# Uploading to Amazon S3 via ng-file-upload; Error 400

Tags: python, angularjs, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload a photo to S3. I have tested my S3 bucket and my policy/signature generator with the ng-file-upload [demo tool](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/) and have successfully used it to upload the photo to my bucket.

---

*Edit:* A key difference seems to be the addition of a header:

`Authorization:Token 3j4fl8jk0lqfkj4izj2w3ljfopljlwep1010notreal`

That is present in my code but not in the demo page. Perhaps it's my angular app.

---

Installed through bower, took the relevant components, tried to upload a file, and get an error that looks like this:

```
 400: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <Error>
 <Code>InvalidArgument</Code> 
 <Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message> 
 <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
 <ArgumentValue>Token 3j4fl8jk0lqfkj4izj2w3ljfopljlwep1010notreal</ArgumentValue>
 <RequestId>F1F5FK-not-real-81FED9CA</RequestId>
 <HostId>CQEW98p3D2e+pVz-not-real-codeu28m7asqpGjagL3409gj3f4kijKJpofk</HostId>
 </Error>
```

Searching around, I've noted many 400 Errors but not many cases with the `ArgumentValue` as `Token [some-code-here]`.

Looking at [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html), `InvalidArgument` is a bit opaque for someone rather new to AWS.

And here is the policy that I'm encoding (Python):

```
#exptime = '2100-07-31T06:23:35Z' #for debugging
policy_document = {"expiration": exptime,
    "conditions": [ 
      {"bucket": settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}, 
      ["starts-with", '$key', ""],
      {"acl": "private"},
      ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
      ["starts-with", "$filename", ""],
      ["content-length-range", 0, 5000000] 
    ]
  }
```

To reiterate, this policy with the aforementioned demo worked, so I expect a problem on my front-end implementation:

```
$scope.upload = function(file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
                method: 'POST',
                fields: {
                    key: file.name,
                    AWSAccessKeyId: myAccessKeyId,
                    acl: 'private',
                    policy: myPolicyEncoded,
                    signature: mySignatureEncoded,
                    "Content-Type": file.type === null || 
                        file.type === '' ? 'application/octet-stream' : file.type,
                    filename: file.name
                },
                file: file
            });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took me a while to find it, but as my edit pointed out, looking into the request header a token used in the Angular app's login/auth process was being sent as a default, and Amazon's service didn't like that. Removing the header in the http request for this specific case solved the issue.

The upload service on my front-end thus looks like:

```
$scope.upload = function(file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
                method: 'POST',
                fields: {
                    key: file.name,
                    AWSAccessKeyId: myAccessKeyId,
                    acl: 'private',
                    policy: myPolicyEncoded,
                    signature: mySignatureEncoded,
                    "Content-Type": file.type === null || 
                        file.type === '' ? 'application/octet-stream' : file.type,
                    filename: file.name
                },
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': undefined
                },
                file: file
            });
}
```

Comment: After 3 hours, this answer did the job!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but i just came to this error.

Instead of removing the custom header you could put that header in the CORS Policy like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```