# PUT NSData to PreSigned URL from S3 with Alamofire.upload(...) not working on iOS 8

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, ios8, alamofire

The following code works fine on iOS9 but when run on iOS8 it fails and Amazon is returning error 400. The response only contain headers:

- Connection = close; "Content-Type" = "application/xml"; Date = "Wed,
  13 Apr 2016 12:19:21 GMT"; Server = AmazonS3; ...

The NSData is an image and the Content-Type is "image/png", which tells amazon not to store it as a "binary/octet-stream".

```
func uploadFile(locationURL: String, http: Alamofire.Method, mimeType: String, fileData: NSData) -> ApiCaller {
    Alamofire.upload(http, locationURL, headers: ["Content-Type": mimeType], data: fileData)
        .progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
            if let uploadProgress = self.uploadProgress {
                uploadProgress(bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesWritten);
            }
        }
        .response { (req, res, json, error) in
            self.returnResult(req, res: res, json: json, error: error, tag: 0)
            return();
        }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy guided me to the answer: [Other guy having similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31374348/3077522)

It turns out that the HTTPAdditionalHeaders on the manager session in Alamofire had headers from my previous calls and Amazon S3 didn't like this on iOS 8.

Therefore all I needed, was to clear the headers before using the .upload(...) function.

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [:];
```

Comment: As of 3/17, the current syntax is `Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = [:]`